# Do you have to set HtmlBody / TextBody in Yii 2 mailer if you are using a mail view?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Been reading about [sending mail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html) in `Yii 2` and noticed you can pass in mail views.

For example:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose([
    'html' => 'contact-html',
    'text' => 'contact-text',
]);
```

...as well as use mail layouts.

However, my question is, if all your content is going to be contained within the views then what is the purpose of the below:

```
// Set body
$mail->setHtmlBody($email_data['html_msg']);
$mail->setTextBody($email_data['message']);
```

Do you still have to set them - how does this work?

Comment: you still have to set the body and message to initialize to send the message

Comment: @unixmiah What do we set them to? An empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand you're question, i had to read it over.

if you want to use HTML template rendering and another for text, you'd do this:

```
Yii::$app->mail->compose(['html' => '@app/mail-templates/html-email-01', 'text' => '@app/mail-templates/mail'], [/*Some params for the view */])
     ->setFrom('from@me.com')
     ->setTo('someone@domain.com')
     ->setSubject('An email')
     ->send();
```

the path to the view can also be relative, like inside a controller 
(for example, ['html' => 'html-email-01']).

in your post you mentioned

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
    ->setTo('to@domain.com')
    ->setSubject('Message subject')
    ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
    ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
    ->send();
```

you don't have to set

```
$mail->setHtmlBody($email_data['html_msg']);
$mail->setTextBody($email_data['message']);
```

if you're going to be using mail views

Comment: Oh ok...... now I'm a little confused as your comment differs to your answer haha...... so I DON'T have to do anything with `setHtmlBody` or `setTextBody` if I am using views right?

Comment: sorry, i wrote my answer as if I was writing code. no you don't.